# Atlas count a total value from field

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, atlas

I need to create an Atlas and display several informations.
I have 2 layers:

- the A, this is a shape with polygons and 2 fields (name of each polygon and an ID)
- the B, shape with points and 3 fields (name, date, number)

I use the A shape in the Atlas but I need to display in a label the sum of numbers from the field of the B shape for the differents polygon with the Atlas.

I need to display the sum of numbers according to the date (the sum from de number B's field depending of the date I choose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dynamic approach would be to use an `aggregate` expression for the labelling.

This expression filters both by date (using the atlas page name) and by a `name` column that is in both the `polygon` and `points` layers.

Apply it to the label expression of the `polygon` layer.

```sql
with_variable('date', to_date(substr(@atlas_pagename, 1, 10), 'dd-MM-yyyy'),  -- make a date from the first 10 characters of the atlas page name
 
    aggregate(layer:= 'points',        -- the name of the points layer
              aggregate:= 'sum',       -- sum the values in a field
              expression:= "number",   -- the field you wish to sum
              filter:= "date" = @date and "name" = attribute(@parent, 'name')  

              -- values used to filter
              -- @date is the variable made on the first line
              -- "date" is the date field in the points layer
              -- "name" is the name field in the points layer
              -- attribute(@parent, 'name') is the value in the name field of the current polygon
    )

)
```

- Set an expression for the Atlas page name using the date as the first 10 characters.
- change this date to filter the points that are summed

[image]

Current atlas page name

[image]

For 04-01-2022, for the polygon with `name 1`, the total is 14:
[image]
[image]

**Toggle the Preview Atlas button off and on to update the labels each time you change the date in the page name expression**

Answer (score 1):

toolbox: Processing --> Toolbox (search for tools)

1. spatial join a on b

   - tool: "Join attributes by location"
   - base layer = b (points)
   - join layer = a (polygons)
   - Geometric predicate = intersects
2. aggregate (under Vector geometry)

   - tool: Aggregate
   - Input layer = joined layer (result from above)
   - Group by expression = "date" + "name_of_polygon" (considering date and name are strings)
   - Aggregates

     - number - sum
     - add new field - expression: "date" + "name_of_polygon"
       [image: inputs of aggregate]
3. now you could use the aggregated point layer or join aggregated result back to Layer A (using one to many option)